# laravel 4 override Auth::user() for all auth drivers

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I need to override `Auth::user()` for all drivers.
I created a class 'MyGuard' that override Illuminate\Auth\Guard, but I don't know how to say to the entire application to use MyGuard instead of Illuminate\Auth\Guard.
Probably i can't do that because Guard is directly instantiated in Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager using

`new Guard($provider, ...)`.

`Auth::extends()` seems to serve only to create new drivers.
I don't want to write directly inside original Guard class.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to override Auth::user()? What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you are creating new Auth for your application but don't want to use original `Auth` from Laravel, then comment or delete that `'Auth' => 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth',` line in `app/config/app.php` file.

Comment: Auth::user() return the instance of actual user logged in, in my application this entity may change so I need to put another control in Illuminate\Auth\Guard::user(). If i put this control directly into the original class it works, but write over core classes isn't a good idea.

Comment: You'd probably have to swap out the `AuthManager` binding in the container as well for this since all the drivers return a new `Guard` instance inside the `AuthManager`.

Comment: So as expected I should: extends AuthManager; override all methods that return a Guard instance; swap the original \Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider with a service provider that binding 'auth' in the container returns my AuthManager.